# Fix following id's when a row is deleted

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some rows, each row has a unique key. When a row is deleted from the table, all rows that are below this row should be 'moved up'. Is there some built in function in MySQL that does this or should I just do it with PHP or perhaps `UPDATE table SET id=id-1 WHERE id > deletedid`?

Using the last one seems a bit messy.
What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't think mysql has a build in feature for this... But can I ask you why you would need this? The reason this isn't done is to prevent the moving of information when there is a direct link, for example when load pages from your database and you set pageID=2 as your homepage and number 1 is deleted your homepage wouldnt work anymore... Remember that users will never see the background process so absolute neatness on the back end isn't needed

Comment: Though I don't know why you want that I guess you should re-think that idea. Usually you do not want to re-use a primary key.

Comment: I realize the question itself is a bit messy too. Let me explain: I have a table in the database that is a direct mapping to a table in a control panel. The rows in the control panel can be moved up and down. I move these rows by swapping their id's with the row that has their id plus or minus one.

Comment: Ah! Then my answer is slightly out of date. Yes, "UPDATE table SET id=id-1 WHERE id > deletedid" is probably quite correct for this situation: you explicitly want to shift them all down.

Comment: You should probably use a separate column for "order_id" and update that rather than their primary key

Comment: Ok, I'll do that then. And after that I need to make sure I update the auto_increasement field to the right value, too.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, I thought about that, but the order key would always be a unique value which I would use to identify a row, so it kind of beats the point.

Comment: It means you're not messing with the id of your row, which might break something later ;-)

Comment: But I don't use it for anything else, so I don't think that it really matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why do you want to do this? I know it's ugly to have holes in your unique ID sequence, but the downside of invalidating any references to IDs from outside the database is normally very much greater. The normal thing is to just accept the sequence won't be contiguous. If these represent a sequence, consider just sorting by the order rather than expecting the N'th value to have value N (any sort of iteration should provide its own index somewhere for this use).
2. If the value is one you set yourself, and you definitely want to keep it as having values from 1 to N (N="number of rows"), and you want to keep the sequence of values even if they're not in the order the rows were inserted, then "UPDATE table SET id=id-1 WHERE id > deletedid" is probably the best answer.
3. If the value is an auto_increment field, and you don't care which numbers go with with rows as long as each row has a number from 1 to N, you can alternatively do ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN 'columnname' and then ALTER TABLE again to add the column again, and the database will regenerate the ids from 0. (Not necessarily in the same order, though it often is.)
4. There may be a way to renumber only the rows after that point, but (according to a quick google) it doesn't look like there's anything easier than what you're already planning.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to ensure that the column is not a foreign-key for any other table.

Then you can try this (I am not 100% positive it will work):

```
DELETE FROM 
  MyTable
WHERE 
  id = deletedid;

UPDATE 
  table
SET 
  id=id-1
WHERE 
  id > deletedid
ORDER BY 
  id
```

As stated in mysql [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

> If the ORDER BY clause is specified,
>   the rows are updated in the order that
>   is specified.

and in this way you ensure uniqueness of the field.